# How to Spotify recognizes oEmbed as a device?

Tags: javascript, iframe, embed, spotify

I'm using iframe to embed Spotify to my web app. But Spotify doesn't recognize it as a device, so I can't use Spotify API to play/pause, seek or skip track!!!

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by `Spotify doesn't recognize it as a device`?

Comment: When I run this request https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/reference/get-a-users-available-devices, it only shows devices that is open by https://open.spotify.com, not show my iframe embed Spotify device.